# How do I remove left recursion in JavaCC?

Tags: parsing, recursion, compiler-construction, javacc

I am trying to remove left  recursion in JavaCC for expr, which should be defined as:

```
expr ::= statement binary_op statement
| **(** expr **)**
| identifier **(** arg **)**
| statement
```

This code causes a left recursion in my program:

```
void expr() : { }
{

    < LPAREN > simpleExpr() < RPAREN >
    | < IDENTIFIER > <LPAREN > arg() < RPAREN >
    | statement()
}

void simpleExpr() : { }
{
    statement() binary_op() statement()
}
```

statement is defined as:

```
statement ::= id | - id | number | false | true | expr

void statement() : { }
{
    < ID > | < NOT_OP > < ID >
    | < DIGIT >
    | < TRUE >
    | < FALSE >
    | expr() 
}
```

The error I get in my program:

```
Left recursion detected: "expr... --> statement... --> expr..."
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: There is no left-recursion in the code you've shown. If there is left recursion in your grammar, it must be in the `statement` rule (or mutually between `expr` and `statement`).

Comment: Hi, there is a left recursion becuase I get an error in my program. I have updated my question to show the error.

Comment: I realized you are right, the left recursion is caused by `expr` and `statement`. @sepp2k

Comment: Where in the spec is it stated that a statement() can be an expr() ?

Comment: I have updated the question to what a statement is in the spec. @ErwinSmout

Answer (score 2):

According to your grammar, a `statement` can be an `expr` and an `expr` can be a `statement`.  Therefore the languages generated by these two nonterminal are the same.  You don't need both nonterminals.  I'd suggest removing the definition of `statement` and changing the definition of `expr` to this

```
void expr() : { }
{
      < ID >
    | < NOT_OP > < ID >
    | < DIGIT >
    | < TRUE >
    | < FALSE >
    | < LPAREN > simpleExpr() < RPAREN >
    | < IDENTIFIER > <LPAREN > arg() < RPAREN > 
}
```

Then either

- replace `statement` with `expr` everywhere in the remaining grammar (including the definition of `simpleExpr`)
- or add this rule:

  ```
  void statement() : { }
  {
      expr()
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your usage of the id `statement` is quite unusual. It looks more like a `literal`.
2. In your `statement` you should remove the line `| expr()`. Otherwise a `statement` might be an `expression` and an `expression` might be a `statement` ... how should the parser then decide?

Comment: Of course that changes the language generated by the grammar. For example in the original grammar `expr` derives `LPAREN`  `IDENTIFIER` `LPAREN` `arg` `RPAREN` `binaryOp` `DIGIT` `RPAREN`. But in the modified grammar it does not.